# How to print from iPad using bluetooth?

Tags: ipad, printing, bluetooth

I have a printer which supports the **printing over the bluetooth network** . 

I searched for printing from iOS and went through the Apple documentation on  UIPrintInteractionController class . But no where it has been specified whether it can use bluetooth to make the connection to the printer or not ? I know it works on the Wifi .

Can any one suggest any tutorial or any link on printing from iPad using bluetooth ( if at all possible )

 Please help me with this !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AirPrint protocol uses a WiFi network to detect compatible devices. I don't think it's possible to print via Bluetooth in iOS as of yet.

Comment: I believe those applications require a helper print server application that runs on Mac OS X or Windows.

Comment: Yes you are right , I searched a lot on this and came with the same conclusion .